# Yii2 SwiftMailer sending email via remote smtp server (gmail)

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

I want to send emails via my gmail account.

My mailer config:

```
[
'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
'useFileTransport' => false,//set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
'transport' => [
    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'port' => '587',
    'encryption' => 'tls',
    ],
]
```

I wrote command MailController:

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
use Yii;

/**
* Sanding mail
* Class MailController
* @package app\commands
*/
class MailController extends Controller
{
    private $from = 'my@gmail.com';
    private $to = 'to@gmail.com';

    public function actionIndex($type = 'test', $data = null)
    {
        Yii::$app->mailer->compose($type, ['data' => $data])
            ->setFrom($this->from)
            ->setTo($this->to)
            ->setSubject($this->subjects[$type])
            ->send();
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to run: `php yii mail`

I get: `sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found`

But why it requires sendmail if I want just SMTP connection to smtp.gmail.com?

Comment: Are you sure this email component config is for key 'mailer'? According to this config it is not even supposed to try to send email as "'useFileTransport' => true" means it only saves message to file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you have configured the mailer wrongly. Because it is still using the default mail function. From the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-swiftmailer-mailer.html) the configuration should be like below. The mailer should be inside `components`.

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
    ...
],
```

One more suggestion is to use port "465" and encryption as "ssl" instead of port "587", encryption "tls".

Comment: Ooops. I forgot that commands have there own config file, not web.php. Now mailer is working fine.

Comment: @zeiz If you found the solution, post it as an answer and accept it. So it will be helpful to others..

Answer (score 3):

Yii2 Has different config files for web and console works. So you need to config **both of them**. Regarding this issue, I had to make mail config file (for example `mailer.php`) and include it in both config files (web.php & console.php) like:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'mailer' => require(__DIR__ . '/mailer.php'),
    ...
],
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be useful for someone as reference:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'port' => 587,
        'encryption' => 'tls',
        'streamOptions' => [ 
            'ssl' => [ 
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
            ],
        ]
    ],
]
```