# Yii2 Send email by any username and password

Tags: php, email, yii2, sendmail

How can I ***send an email by any email account and password***, like below or by any another way:

```
$mail->setFrom('from@gmail.com');
$mail->setPassword('abcxyz');
$mail->setHeader('This is a header');
$mail->setBCC('bcc@gmail.com');
$mail->setCC('cc@gmail.com');
$mail->setContent('contents absjadha ');
$mail->send();
```

I have over *100 emails*, and I want to ***use it to send emails to my users*** or ***let them send emails to the others by my tool***. Is there any **Yii2** plugin or extension that can help me to solve this problem? Providing that all their ***email and password stored in my database***. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are looking for solution with gmail the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29600264/3364821 - it applies to other providers as well only with different configuration. BUT if you want your users to give you their credentials to use their email account I don't see that coming.

Comment: Users should use their credentials to do that, we just create a front-end and send email...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this directly in the **Controller**

```
Yii::$app->mailer->setTransport([
    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'username' => $emailFrom,
    'password' => $password,
    'port' => '465',
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    // smtp.gmail.com    ---   StartTLS ---   587
    // smtp.gmail.com    ---    SSL       ---      465
]);
```

before this line

Yii::$app->mail->compose('@common/mail/cron_acordo', ['model_definicoes' => $model_definicoes])

Comment: This may be dangerous, since it changes global mailer, which could be used in other places. In worst cases you could send some sensitive messages using Gmail account of one of your users (sent messages could be automatically saved in Gmail mailbox, so this user will have access to all messages you've sent using his account).

Comment: @rob006 is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Yeah, I posted it in my answer.

Comment: I used your method but It cant not run

Comment: "it cannot run" is not really descriptive... Why it does not work? Any error messages? On what line?

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate custom mailer component for this task:

```
$mailer = Yii::createObject([
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => $userHost,
        'username' => $userEmail,
        'password' => $userPassword,
        'port' => 587,
        'encryption' => 'tls',
    ],
]);

$mail = $mailer->compose('@common/mail/cron_acordo', ['model_definicoes' => $model_definicoes]);
$mail->setFrom('from@gmail.com');
$mail->setPassword('abcxyz');
$mail->setHeader('This is a header');
$mail->setBCC('bcc@gmail.com');
$mail->setCC('cc@gmail.com');
$mail->setContent('contents absjadha ');
$mail->send($mailer);
```

Comment: $mail->setFrom('from@gmail.com');
$mail->setPassword('abcxyz');
$mail->setHeader('This is a header');
$mail->setBCC('bcc@gmail.com');
$mail->setCC('cc@gmail.com');
$mail->setContent('contents absjadha ');
$mail->send();
Method nor found!

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have setup email credentials to send emails: for more info you can read [read email tutorial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing)
So in you config file either in `main.php or main-local.php`

```
'mailer' => [
           'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
           'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
           'transport' => [
               'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
               'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
               'username' => 'emailaddress',
               'password' => '******',
               'port' => '587',
               'encryption' => 'tls',
           ],
           'useFileTransport' => false,
       ],
```

Once the mailer component is configured, you can use the following code to send an email message:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
    ->setTo('to@domain.com')
    ->setSubject('Message subject')
    ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
    ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
    ->send();
```

In the above example the method compose() creates an instance of the mail message, which then is populated and sent. You may put more complex logic in this process if needed:

```
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose();
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $message->setFrom('from@domain.com');
} else {
    $message->setFrom(Yii::$app->user->identity->email);
}
$message->setTo(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
    ->setSubject('Message subject')
    ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
    ->send();
```